# Making title bars transparent in Unity isn't working

Tags: unity, compiz, themes, transparency

I've found this way to make title bars in Unity transparent:

- Open `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to org.compiz.gwd
- Modify `metacity-theme-active-opacity` and `metacity-theme-inactive-opacity`

However, ths method isn't working. Please help me. And tell me what additional info you need...

Raring x64